# R BMN console output

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using `BMNPseudo.single` from `BMN` package. This function generates a lot of outputs that I would like to hide. I've tried `sink` but it isn't working.

```
library(BMN)
mat<-matrix(rnorm(4),2,2)
BMNPseudo.single(mat,0.02)
```

Comment: Have you tried `capture.output`?

Comment: Yes, it isn't working in Rstudio. i need something like `/dev/null` but for Rstudio on windows

Comment: Or something to disable console while running my code.